# Arduino. The length of NULL

Tags: null, arduino, strlen

This is not an question, I just want to share a headache I had for a while.

Why I got 1 in:

```
Serial.println(strlen(NULL))
```

Because of this macro:

```
#define NULL ((char *)0)
```

I was expecting 0, but the fact is that I was calculating the length of '0', that is, 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not calculating the length of '0' but the length of the string that is at address 0.

strlen's parameter is `char *` which is a pointer to char.

You supply it a pointer who's value is 0 (points to address 0). strlen looks at the address 0 and calculates the length of the string starting at this address. The end of the string marked by 0 which might be the content of the address 0, making it zero length string.

Comment: The content of the address 0 could be \0 or 5 or 'c'.... it should depend on the memory sate. Am I right? In that case, the length will be zero or one

Comment: If the content of address 0 is nor 0, strln will continue counting untill it reaches a 0 which is the string termination. So the return value depends on the content of the following memory addreses.